# LIBGDX keeps printing "DefaultShaderProvider: Creating new shader" to terminal

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx

I am creating a 3d game in libGDX. For some reason my game keeps printing

```
DefaultShaderProvider: Creating new shader
```

in the terminal. This is driving me absolutely insane because I can not debug my program with the terminal because of the spamming of that line. I checked my code for anything that would print this but I can not find anything that would.

Could anyone tell me why this is happening?

Here is my code:

```
public class puppetDemo implements ApplicationListener {
public PerspectiveCamera camera;
public ModelBatch modelBatch;
public ModelInstance box;
public ModelInstance sphere;
public Array<ModelInstance> instances = new Array<ModelInstance>();
public AssetManager assets;
public Lights lights;
public CameraInputController camController;

public boolean loading = true;

@Override
public void create() {
    camera = new PerspectiveCamera(67, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),
            Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    camera.position.set(10f, 0f, -100f);
    camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
    camera.near = 0.1f;
    camera.far = 300f;
    camera.update();

    lights = new Lights();
    lights.ambientLight.set(0.4f, 0.4f, 0.4f, 1f);
    lights.add(new DirectionalLight().set(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, -1f, -0.8f,
            -0.2f));

    assets = new AssetManager();
    assets.load("data/box.obj", Model.class);
    assets.load("data/sphere.obj", Model.class);

}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {

}

@Override
public void render() {
    Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),
            Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);


    modelBatch = new ModelBatch();

    modelBatch.begin(camera);// Begin Rendering
    modelBatch.render(instances, lights);
    modelBatch.end();// End Rendering
}

@Override
public void pause() {

}

@Override
public void resume() {

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    modelBatch.dispose();
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `new ModelBatch()` in your `render` method, this is creating a new instance of the `DefaultShaderProvider`:

```
public ModelBatch() {
  this(new RenderContext(new DefaultTextureBinder(DefaultTextureBinder.ROUNDROBIN, 1)),
       new DefaultShaderProvider(),
       new DefaultRenderableSorter());
}
```

Looking at the source for `DefaultShaderProvider` you'll notice logging output in the `createShader` method:

```
@Override
protected Shader createShader(final Renderable renderable) {
  Gdx.app.log("DefaultShaderProvider", "Creating new shader");
  // ...
}
```

Instantiate `modelBatch` in the `create` method instead of in `render` and I suspect you'll only see the output once. If not, it might be worth filing an issue to have logging statement removed as it seems unnecessary.